# PHP Variable in SQL Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I receive the following error when I use a variable in my SQL statement:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL     server version for the right syntax to use near '1 = 86 WHERE ID = 284' at line 1
```

The code for the SQL (which is being used in PHP) is:

```
for($l=0; $l<count($item); $l++) {
$query = "UPDATE  members SET  item" . $l+1 . " = ".$itemID[$l]." WHERE ID = ".$_SESSION['id'];
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error);
}
```

I know that the error isn't coming from the Session Variable, but if is coming from `l`, I don't know why. I thought I did everything correctly. Why do I receive that error and how to I prevent it?

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will probably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Your query is mixing user data in without proper escaping:

```
for($l=0; $l<count($item); $l++) {
  /* Use sprintf to avoid injecting arbitrary strings into query */
  $query = sprintf("UPDATE  members SET item%d=? WHERE ID=?", $l + 1);

  /* Prepare the statement and bind specific user data values into placeholders */
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bind_param('is', $itemId[$l], $_SESSION['id']);

  /* Execute and get result */
  $result = $stmt->execute();
}
```

The `or die` pattern is about the worst possible way to handle errors. You'd be better off raising exceptions and catching those somewhere you can recover from them and present a user-friendly message.

Comment: Excellent answer; this is the only one that addresses the injection issues and the field name problem.

Comment: I'd redesign the schema to avoid having columns with such awful names and avoid looping to update. This design violates the [Zero, One, or Infinite rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "UPDATE  members SET  item" . ($l+1) . " = ".$itemID[$l]." WHERE ID = ".$_SESSION['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. What you are doing there is **very bad style**. Think about doing it differently! Hints about mysqli and parameters are all over the answers and comments here.
2. There is no reason to use a `for` loop and use `count($item)` many `UPDATE` statements when you could do it with 1 (one)!

   ```
   UPDATE members SET item1=value1, item2=value2, ... WHERE ID = ".$_SESSION['id'];
   ```
3. To find the exact cause of the problem I recommend you output the `$query`, have a look at it **and add it to your question here**.
4. The problem seems to lie with the delimiters `"` and `'`.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
  $query = "UPDATE  members SET  item'".$l+1."' = '".$itemID[$l]." ' 
            WHERE ID = '".$_SESSION['id']."' ";
```

or this

```
 $query = "UPDATE  members SET  item'".$l+1."' = $itemID[$l]
            WHERE ID = '".$_SESSION['id']."' ";
```

Comment: Both of these would produce `... SET item 0+1 = ...`, which would be a syntax error.

Comment: Actually, I think these would still be a problem. They would produce something like `... SET item '1' = ...`, which won't work, either.